# Is really impossible to write code in an mvc master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

All I want to do is to write something like

```
<%=Html.ScriptInclude("~/Scripts/jquery.1.2.6.js")%>
```

When I do that I get an error:

> The Controls collection cannot be
>   modified because the control contains
>   code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Release Candidate 1.

Is that impossible to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside a `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">` tag. There was a known bug in RC1 that caused this problem. Check page 23 of the [release notes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=137661&clcid=0x409) .

I haven't upgraded to 1.0, so I don't know if this was fixed or not.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Not impossible.  I do exactly that.  Code snippet from a recent project below.  What seems to be the problem?

Note that `StyleSheet` and `Javascript` are my own extension methods, as is the `DatedContent` extension on UrlHelper.  To get your own extension methods to work you'll need to import the namespace containing them at the top of your page.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcExtensions" %>

<%= Html.StyleSheet( Url.DatedContent( "~/Content/styles/themes/jquery-ui-theme.css" ) )%> 
<%= Html.StyleSheet( Url.DatedContent( "~/Content/styles/Site.css" ), "all" ) %>
<%= Html.Javascript( Url.Content( "~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ) ) %>
<%= Html.Javascript( Url.Content( "~/Scripts/ui/ui-all-1.7.1.min.js" ) ) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:

```
<script src="../../Script/jquery.1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @TStamper, if you are using ASP.NET MVC and your .js file is in /Scripts default folder, then it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing...

```
<%= Html.ScriptInclude("~/Scripts/jquery.1.2.6.js")%>
```

...to...

```
<%# Html.ScriptInclude("~/Scripts/jquery.1.2.6.js")%>
```

(Changing **=** to **#**)